# How to draw a free-form selection area?

Tags: paint.net

Is it possible to somehow draw a polygon or a free-form region in Paint.Net and later select what's inside it?  If so, how?  (Other than using the Rectangle Select capability.)

A note: I have no clue about the use of layers.  If the solution involves layers, I would really appreciate it if you could break down the steps involved.  (I **want** to learn layers, but somehow have never learned basic the conceptual building block necessary for understanding it.)

Comment: Have you taken a look at or considered asking on the [forum](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/22006-polygon-select-tool) yet?

Comment: +1 thank you for the link.  to be honest, stackexchange places are my first go-to place.  but I will check it out.  thanks again.

Comment: Could you also suggest a tutorial on the fundamentals of layers use?  Thanks again.

Comment: Off hand I don't know of any, but I'm sure you can find lots if you search the net. Most of the examples might deal with popular programs such as Photoshop, but I guess the basics should be the same.